# Text in Semantic UI React is breaking the grid only from the right side

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

In Semantic UI React, I defined a grid that has two columns. If the content is long it does not break to the next line but breaking its column border to the next column. Why is this happening? is it a bug in my or Semanic UI React code?

[image]

Here is the corresponding code:

```
<Grid key={experience.id}>
  <Grid.Column mobile="12" tablet="13" computer="14">
    {experienceRoleStyle(experience.role)}
    {experienceCompanyStyle(experience.company)}
    {experienceDateStyle(getRandomDate())}
    <p className="mt-3">
      xsluixisxkhsbkxgsvkxgvsytxvkusybxkyhbsxlsunxsbhxybxsklnjxkshbkxuvsxxkshbkxjhbskuxvksvbxkhjbsjlhbxljhsbxkjhbskxhbslxsxsxsiyxhsiygxbukysbx
    </p>
  </Grid.Column>
  <Grid.Column mobile="4" tablet="3" computer="2">
    <Icon
      name={experience.company.toLowerCase()}
      floated="right"
      size="huge"
    />
  </Grid.Column>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you also show the code for the card the grid is inside?

Comment: @BasvanderLinden The whole component above is wrapped by another `<Grid> <Grid.Column> .... </Grid.Column><Grid>` pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, all you need to add a class having `word-break` property to the element containing the long text. Semantic grid doesnt handle it for you but gives you freedom to choose any break strategy. You may want to read these
[word-wrap](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) and [word-break](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)

This could be you class

> .text-break{
> word-wrap: break-word;
> }

and your element would look like this

`<p className="mt-3 text-break">      xsluixisxkhsbkxgsvkxgvsytxvkusybxkyhbsxlsunxsbhxybxsklnjxkshbkxuvsxxkshbkxjhbskuxvksvbxkhjbsjlhbxljhsbxkjhbskxhbslxsxsxsiyxhsiygxbukysbx  </p>`

Comment: I tried what you mentioned, however, did not work:

`<p
  className="mt-3"
  style={{
    wordWrap: "break-word"
  }}
>
  ljnxkjhsbxkjgvsjgxcvsjhgxvhgsVKXGVSJGxvKSXVSKGXvkSGXVKADUCBKUVBCILHDBHCGVAKJGVX
  AKJHX HSV JXHVASJYXVKJGVX JHA JHXA
</p>;`

Comment: `<p className="mt-3" style={{"word-break":"break-all"}}>
                xsluixisxkhsbkxgsvkxgvsytxvkusybxkyhbsxlsunxsbhxybxsklnjxkshbkxuvsxxkshbkxjhbskuxvksvbxkhjbsjlhbxljhsbxkjhbskxhbslxsxsxsiyxhsiygxbukysbx
              </p>` this works